# Can't get answer on eyeQ TVPROVIDER_LOOKUP

Tags: api, gracenote

I've got some trouble getting answer from the eyeQ API with TVPROVIDER_LOOKUP.
When I try the example query, no problem. But when I try another country (eg France), I get no answer at all.
Here's my query :

```
<QUERIES>
<LANG>fra</LANG>
<COUNTRY>france</COUNTRY>
    <AUTH>
        <CLIENT>xxxxxxxxx</CLIENT>
        <USER>xxxxxx</USER>
    </AUTH>
    <QUERY CMD="TVPROVIDER_LOOKUP">
        <POSTALCODE>75000</POSTALCODE>
    </QUERY>
</QUERIES>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the free eyeQ API currently doesn't support TV Provider Lookup with postal codes outside of the United States. This may be added in the future, or you could look into a commercial license.

Comment: Thanks for that information, that was driving me crasy ! I'll get in touch with the commercial team :)